# First Cluster stay visible when zooming on Android Google Map Clusters

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, cluster-computing

I managed to implement a working cluster manager for my GMap. However, when I zoom, the first cluster remains visible. When I set the Algorithm to GridBaseAlgorithm, I work correctly but the clusters are not located in the right place.

Here is the code on my MapFragment:

```
private void setUpClusterer(GoogleMap mMap) {

    // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
    // (Activity extends context, so we can pass 'this' in the constructor.)
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(context, mMap);

   // mClusterManager.setAlgorithm(new NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm<ToiletMarker>());

    // Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
    // manager.
    mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());

    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(mClusterManager);
    mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(this);

    mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<ToiletMarker>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClusterItemClick(ToiletMarker item) {
            clickedClusterItem = item;
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Add cluster items (markers) to the cluster manager.
    addItems();

    mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().setOnInfoWindowAdapter(
            new MyCustomAdapterForItems());
}

private void addItems() {
    for (Toilet toilet : toiletArrayList) {
        Location location = toilet.getLocation();
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lon = location.getLongitude();

        ToiletMarker item = new ToiletMarker(lat, lon, toilet);
        mClusterManager.addItem(item);
    }
    mClusterManager.cluster();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Map ready");
    mMap = googleMap;

    setUpClusterer(mMap);
}

@Override
public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(ToiletMarker myItem) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "clicked on myItem : " + myItem.getPosition().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public class MyCustomAdapterForItems implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.markerlayout, null);

            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + latLng.latitude + "," + latLng.longitude));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            //Do stuff
        // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
        return v;
    }
```

Here are 2 images :
[image: First cluser 200+]

[image: Zoomed, first cluster 200+ always here !]

EDIT :

After spend an hour trying to solve, I finally got what happen: The thing is that the cluster manager is working correctly, the problem is that my method which populates the map was being called twice.

To solve this issue just add mMap.clear(); before adding markers :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/yaroslav-android/7c72a12d5661ea3b5dc672bab50520d5) you may look at my custom `ClusterRenderer` and try to implement with your edits and needs.

The main thing is:

```
override fun shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster: Cluster<MapClusterItem>?): Boolean {
       val isZoomLevelSuites = currentZoomLevel < MAX_ZOOM_LVL - POINT_ZOOM_LVL
       return super.shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster) && isZoomLevelSuites
}
```

It should not render cluster after some level of zoom that you will specify. Hope it will be helpful!

Comment: That's an old question, I managed to fix this but I can't remember how ^^

Comment: Oh, did not look at asked timestamp :D

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've added markers to map and to clusterManager at the same time.
If you add item to clusterManager - you already have marker on the map.